# Can you guess the approximate size in mm of Snellen/vision chart letter?

Tags: optics, vision

I searched a lot but nobody is telling the size of letters of 6x6 vision.

Basically, I need to create a rough sketch of any letter of a 6x6 row in Snellen chart.

Some sites say it is 8.7 mm from 6 meters. Now this is really really confusing for a man like me who is not a student of Physics any more. Does it mean it *appears* (how?) 8.7 mm from 6 meters but actual size is less or more? Or does it actually mean that when you take a scale with you and place it on chart and measure it, it is actually 8.7 mm irrespective of how far you are standing?

And if it's not 8.7mm how can I get an approx. idea of it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a physics question

Comment: @Aaron Stevens where can I ask this from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Snellen eye chart uses letters that are 5 by 5 arc minutes in size, and the width of the lines and spaces composing the block letters is  1 arc minute. This means if you paint a symbol  that is 8.73mm tall, and 8.73mm wide, using a 1.75mm wide brush, you will have a close approximation of the Snellen letters you should  be able to read at a distance of 6 meters if you have standard vision (6/6 (m) or 20/20 (ft)). see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snellen_chart

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to understand those formula and meaning of arc minute to roughly sketch it? I'm great at sketching but not in maths. I need a basic idea.

Comment: @Vikas All you need is something to measure 8.73 mm, make the lines and spaces that make the letter 1/5 of that, 1.75mm. Take an E, for example, draw the upright line 8.73mm high, and 1.75mm wide, now draw the 3 lines to the right until the letter is an 8.73mm square (note the 1.75mm rounded up from 1.7453 is why it's not exactly 1/5 of 8.73)

Comment: Yes I've drawn it. Now I placed it at a wall and read it from 6 meters distance easily. Is my vision 6x6 now?

Comment: @Vikas Yes if you can distinguish it readily, then your vision should be at least 6x6, possibly better, but see an eye doctor if you have any doubt, do not take this as sound medical advice.

Comment: That clears all doubts. Now I'm only thinking what @Farcher said in his comment. If you don't mind can you please decipher that? 3m and 6m thing.

Comment: @Vikas Yes, if you do not have 6 meters of space, you could draw the letter half the size and place it 3 meters away for the same results.

Comment: So I need to read a 4.4 mm letter from 3 meters for a 6x6 vision right?

Comment: @Vikas Yes, actually 4.3633, but you can round off to 4.4mm

Comment: Cool. I assume all things you shared here are correct.

Comment: @Vikas Yes, to the best of my knowledge and as referenced by Wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snellen_chart):

> At exactly 6 metres' distance from the patient, the letters on the 6/6
>   line shall subtend 5 minutes of arc (such that the individual limbs of
>   the letters subtend 1 minute of arc), which means that the chart
>   should be sized such that these letters are 8.73 mm tall and the
>   topmost (6/60) "E" should be 87.3 mm tall. Putting it another way, the
>   eye should be at a distance 68.76 times the height of the top (6/60)
>   letter. The formula is $$w=2d\tan\frac{\theta}2$$

In other words, if you have 6/6 vision, from 6 m you can read a letter that is printed 8.73 mm tall on the chart.

Comment: Okay. But 1 doubt remains. Is it *real* 8.73 mm? I mean it would be almost same as diameter of a pencil? Or does it appears 8.73 mm from 6 meters but actually is larger?

Comment: @Vikas  The statement *such that the individual limbs of the letters subtend 1 minute of arc* answers your question. The angle is called the [visual angle](http://elvers.us/perception/visualAngle/) and is a measure of the size of the object's image on the retina. The larger the angle, the larger the image on the retina and the larger is the perceived size of the object.  So if the chart is $3 \,\rm m$ away from the eye the letters on the chart would have to be approximately half the size of the letters on a chart which is $6 \,\rm m$ away from the eye.

Comment: I have edited the last sentence in my answer to make it clearer that we are talking about the real size of the letter.

Comment: @Farcher really confusing.

Comment: @hdhondt yeah. So it's the print size, not what eyes would see? Further Farcher seems to say something different. Too difficult to understand.

Comment: Yes, it's the print size.

Answer (score -1):

The angle subtended by an object is called the [visual angle](http://elvers.us/perception/visualAngle/) and it determines the size of the image formed on the retina as shown in the diagrams below.

[image]

In the left hand diagram objects $A$ and $B$ differ in size but produce images on the retina of the eye which are the same size so both object **appear** to be the same size.

Here is an example of this with the man in the foreground **appearing** to be larger than the the leaning tower of Pisa.

[image]

The right hand diagram shows that the same object produces a smaller image on the retina as it moves further from the eye and so the objects **appears** to be smaller.

[image]

---

Now considering the chart which relates to this statement

> At exactly 6 metres distance from the patient, the letters on the 6/6 line shall subtend 5 minutes of arc.

$5$ minutes of arc is an angle equal to $\frac {5}{60} = \frac {1}{12}^\circ$.

This visual angle would be achieved if the object (a letter on the chart) was $8.73\,\rm mm$ high.

If for some reason, eg lack of space, the chart could only be $3 \,\rm m$ away, one half of $6\,\rm m$, then to have the same visual angle the letters would need to be(approximately) half the size ie $\frac{8.73}{2} \approx 4.37 \,\rm mm$ high.

With a chart $10\,\rm m$ away the letter size needs to be $\frac {10}{6} \times 8.73 = 14.55 \,\rm mm$ high.

Comment: @PM2Ring - Quite right! Thank you for your input. I will make the correction. In future if you think that I have made an error then feel free to correct it yourself.